# Rust calling trait alias for closure

Tags: rust

I am using a trait to create an alias for a closure so that I do not have to repeat the declaration several times throughout the code, however I cannot work out how to cast the trait back to Fn so that I can call it in main, is this possible?

```
trait Closure: Send + Sync {}
impl <F: Send + Sync> Closure for F where F: Fn(&str) -> bool {}

pub struct Struct {
    pub closure: Box<dyn Closure>
}

impl Struct {
    pub fn new(closure: impl Closure + 'static) -> Self {
        Self{
            closure: Box::new(closure)
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let s = Struct::new(|f: &str| f.is_empty());

    let result: bool = (s.closure)("hello world"); //TODO
    println!("{}", result );
}
```

Comment: Will the closure always be `Fn(&str) -> bool`?

Comment: yes it will always have the same arguments and return type for this struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call a `Box<dyn Closure>` as a method. At that point, all the compiler knows about this type is that it implements `Closure`. It does not know if it is a function, a struct, or anything else, which is why your code will not compile.

You can get solve this by adding an associated method to the `Closure` trait. This is a very common way of modelling functions:

```rust
pub trait Closure: Send + Sync {
    fn call(&self, input: &str) -> bool;
}
```

You can implement it for the `Fn` type:

```rust
impl <F: Send + Sync> Closure for F where F: Fn(&str) -> bool {
    fn call(&self, input: &str) -> bool {
        self(input)
    }
}
```

And call the `Closure` trait object by simply invoking its `call` method:

```rust
let s = Struct::new(|f: &str| f.is_empty());
let result: bool = s.closure.call("hello world");
```

Answer (score 3):

As Ibraheem Ahmed's answer points out, `Closure` doesn't guarantee in general that any type implementing it is a function. But you can do that by adding `Fn` as a supertrait:

```rust
pub trait Closure: Send + Sync + Fn(&str) -> bool {}
```

With this one line changed, your code will compile and run.

The difference between this and the other option of adding an explicit `call` method to the trait is here, `Closure` can **only** be implemented for closures and function pointers — not for structs or enums — because in stable Rust (as of version 1.47.0) there is no way to write an `impl Fn for MyType`. But if you only intend to use this trait with actual closures like `|f: &str| f.is_empty()`, that's no problem.